# Bootstrap form Input not working in grid system unless col-lg-

Tags: input, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

Here is the sample code;

http://www.bootply.com/lHB0p7sBFI

Basically the input textbox works perfect in large screen mode, but if I shrink the web browser to md, sm, or xs I lose all functionality of the input box I cannot enter text after I click on the box.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the second div overlaps on the first division. first div has height of just 1px. to solve the issue either provide height to first div or remove col-* on nested div.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="gallery/new/update/">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" tabindex="1" autofocus="" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>        
    </div>   
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="new-update" class="btn btn-primary">Add Gallery Item(s)
            </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also its better to wrap your col-* into container and row, here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lYWBbgmeFS).